# Land cover img. file - Conversion to TIFF file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, land-cover, land-use

I have a land cover data with 4 classes in .img format. Since I cannot upload it to Google Earth Engine assets because of its format, I needed to convert it to TIFF. format. I tried 'export data' in ArcMap 10.6 to do the conversion. However, when I converted to TIFF file, it gives me 255 classes as follows (I could not show all the classes):

[image]

How can I make a TIFF file with 4 classes?

Comment: The tiff only has 4 classes, not 255. Symbolise by unique values instead of colormap or just inspect the statistics and you will see.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will try that.

Comment: If you look at the properties of the raster (right click in TOC > properties) look at the Source tab, this will confirm it has a color map as suggested by @user2856. You can use the Delete Colormap tool to remove it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks for the help.